# Replacing HTMl.BeginForm with Ajax to avoid QueryParameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am refactoring a piece of code right now on a login page, which is using Html.BeginForm. I think it uses Query parameters under the hood and I am not a big fan of query parameters. I have always used Ajax to call server with a heavy model(Or a sensitive model like login model in this case)

Now, user does not see any difference between two methods when Login is successful because user is getting redirected at the end of Login process anyways. However though, when Login fails and Code stays on the same page to display error, it actually shows the entire model serialized in terms of Query parameters right there in URL(Including username and password).

I have replaced the code with Ajax and it seems to be working fine. However, since it is not my code to start with, I just wanted to make sure that

1. Is there any other(possibly better?) way to handle this situation?
2. What are the advantages of using Html.Beginform over Ajax to start with?

Comment: The only way the values could appear in the url is if it was a `FormMethod.Get` Make it a POST as it should be. And since you want to redirect, there is no point using ajax.

Comment: I changed both ActionMethod and FormMethod both to Post but I still do see the Query parameters in the URL

Comment: Then best guess is you doing something wrong in the controller POST method. If the login fails, your should be adding a `ModelState` error and returning the view - i.e. `return View(model);`

Comment: Hi Stephen, So the problem was that the ActionMethod that I was calling was HTTPPost BUT it was doing a RedirectToAction to an ActionMethod which was a GET and eventually we saw all the parameters in the Query String. So I changed my code to do Return View() instead of RedirectToAction() and it seems to be working fine. You can change your comments suggesting to Return View() to an answer and I will be happy to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not show all the relevant code (the controller methods), but there are 2 reasons why you url would be including the `username` and `password` values.

1) The form in you view is making a GET call, for example you have used

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(yourActionName, yourControllerName, FormMethod.Get))
```

in which case you need to make it a `FormMethod.Post` and include a `[HttpPost]` method in your controller that accepts the model.

2) The other possibility is that your POST method is redirecting back to the GET method (and passing it the `username` and `password` values) if the model is invalid, in which case, do not redirect, but instead, return the view

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    // add `ModelStateError` is login fails
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    // redirect
}
```

Note that using `Html.BeginForm()` is a standard submit that leaves the current page (in the POST method you either redirect or return another copy of the 'same' view) while using ajax methods is for staying on the same page, so they are 2 entirely different things. In your case, you ultimately want to redirect to another page following a successful login, so there is no point using ajax.